# Java program uses wrong locale when jpackaged

Tags: java, gradle, locale, jpackage

I am parsing strings representing German-style numbers (i.e., decimal comma and optional full stop for grouping thousands), e.g., "2.804,13"; this is just done using a `DecimalFormat` based on my desired `Locale`:

```
package loc_test;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ParseNumbers {
    static final DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (String s : new String[] { "2.815,53", "2815,53" }) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s \t-> %s", s, df.parse(s)));
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the desired output, e.g., when compiled and run from the command line:

```
2.815,53        -> 2815.53
2815,53         -> 2815.53
```

However, when I bundle it as a jpackage image (`./gradlew jpackageImage` using Gradle and the [Badass Runtime Plugin](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/)) and run the resulting binary, the output seems to indicate that a wrong locale is used:

```
2.815,53    -> 2.815
2815,53     -> 281553
```

I have tried out a few things (in vain), and the problem does not seem to be in the code itself:

1. Added `Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMANY)` in the `main`. `Locale.getDefault()` will show the German locale, but it has no effect.
2. Explicitly set `-Duser.country=DE` and `-Duser.language=de` via Java command line parameters. `System.getProperty(...)` shows the expected values, but again, no effect. (Also, from the command line, it also works with these being set to the system defaults.)
3. Added `-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR,SPI` to the jpackage Java command line parameters (from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218374/how-to-use-unsupported-locale-in-java-11-and-numbers-in-string-format/65221042#65221042)). Again, I can verify from the `main` that the property is set correctly, but it makes no difference. (And seems to have been an issue with earlier Java versions anyway.)

I have seen the problem first using **Java 16 with Gradle 7.2**; and it has persisted after an update to **Java 17 and Gradle 7.3**. The problem has occurred both on an English Linux system and a German Windows machine.

Using `--info` with the `jpackageImage` command, Gradle shows me which JDK it is using:

```
Starting process 'command '.../.gradle/jdks/jdk-17+35/bin/jpackage''. Working directory: .../LocTest/app Command: .../.gradle/jdks/jdk-17+35/bin/jpackage --type app-image --input .../LocTest/app/build/install/app/lib --main-jar app.jar --main-class LocTest.App --dest .../LocTest/app/build/jpackage --name app --runtime-image .../LocTest/app/build/jre --java-options -Duser.country=DE --java-options -Duser.language=de --java-options -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR,SPI
```

When I use that `.gradle/jdks/jdk-17+35/bin/java` to run the class, i.e., run:

```
~/.gradle/jdks/jdk-17+35/bin/java -cp app/build/classes/java/main loc_test.App`
```

With this, the problem does *not* occur; the numbers are correct.

However, the problem *does* occur when I use the (supposedly same) JRE bundled with the jpackage image, i.e., I get the *wrong* numbers using:

```
./app/build/jpackage/app/lib/runtime/bin/java -cp app/build/classes/java/main/ loc_test.App
```

Why would the `java`, when packaged, ignore the locale?
Am I missing something here, or might this be a bug in jpackage or the plugin, or in the Java release itself?

The whole Gradle example project (very small) [can be found at Github](https://github.com/hansi-b/JpackageLocaleTest).

Comment: Have you verified programmatically the version of Java at runtime?

Comment: CLDR is used first by default in modern Java. You are overruling that. Your change may be justified for the sake of troubleshooting, but I want to make sure you’re aware of [*JEP 252: Use CLDR Locale Data by Default*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252).

Comment: @BasilBourque, thanks for the pointer - CLDR appears to not be a part of the problem: When I add the correct module as pointed out by the accepted answer, I get the right output with and without setting the locale providers. (So I'll be leaving that out.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check what modules are included in your runtime image.

For example when I run `java --list-modules` on JDK 17 I notice this module:

jdk.localedata

I don't know if it is required for this, but I bet that module isn't being included by jpackage unless it is specifically requested.

Run `./app/build/jpackage/app/lib/runtime/bin/java --list-modules` and compare with `~/.gradle/jdks/jdk-17+35/bin/java --list-modules`  to confirm.  Then consider making an image with `jlink` that includes `jdk.localedata` if it was missing to test this hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the issue. The modules listing for the jpackage java consisted of the one entry `java.base@17.0.1`. After adding `modules = ['jdk.localedata']` to my `runtime` configuration in `build.gradle`, that shows up as well, and the numbers are parsed correctly.